# associate new extentions with programs in regedit

Tags: file-extension, regedit

I teach my self everything using trial and error then ask on forums like this my blanks that I can figure out yet.

Today’s question is, can I associate a file extension with a default program to open it using my reg edit.

Example I have the extension .abc and I want it to be opened in word by default. I understand that I can open with by right clicking the mouse but I want to know if it’s possible programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, registered file extensions are located in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Open them with regedit to see how they work !